# MATLAB - Pan a plot independently of other plots in the same axes

Tags: matlab, plot, interactive

If I have multiple plots (A, B, C) on the same axes, is it possible to pan A without panning B and C as well?

If not, is there another way I can accomplish the same goal?

Comment: What do you mean by "pan"? It sounds like you want to move one plot independently of the others, but how do you expect to pan one plot and not the others and still make the values on the axes match the data points correctly?

Comment: @SteveL: you could plot each "lineseries" to different yet superimposed axes. I could show an example if this is something you want to do

Comment: @Amro You should provide an example of this... and maybe even throw in a way to change which axis object is affected by the `scroll` tool. I'd give that answer a +5 if I could - it would be a handy example to have floating around the internet.

Comment: @tmpearce: done, example posted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete example:

```
function example_panning
    %# some random data to plot
    N = 3;
    data = cumsum(rand(1000,N)-0.5);
    labels = {'A', 'B', 'C'};

    %# structure used to store graphic handles
    h = struct();

    %# create figure
    h.fig = figure();

    %# create background axis (used only to provide the white bg)
    pos = get(0,'DefaultAxesPosition');
    h.ax(N+1) = axes('Parent',h.fig, 'Position',pos, ...
        'XTick',[], 'YTick',[], 'ZTick',[], ...
        'HitTest','off', 'HandleVisibility','callback');

    %# plot each line in an individual axis (transparent)
    clr = lines(N);
    for i=1:N
        h.ax(i) = axes('Parent',h.fig, 'Position',pos, ...
            'Color','none', 'Visible','off');
        h.line(i) = plot(h.ax(i), data(:,i), ...
            'Color',clr(i,:), 'DisplayName',labels{i});
    end

    %# link all axes positions
    hlink = linkprop(h.ax, 'Position');
    setappdata(h.fig, 'graphics_linkprop',hlink)

    %# show legend (attached to background axis)
    h.leg = legend(h.ax(end), h.line, labels);

    %# show x/y-labels on all plot axes
    for i=1:N
        xlabel(h.ax(i), 'time')
        ylabel(h.ax(i), 'value')
    end

    %# create toolbar (allows to switch current axis)
    h.tb = uitoolbar(h.fig);
    for i=1:N
        icon = reshape(repmat(clr(i,:),[256 1]), [16 16 3]);
        h.toggle(i) = uitoggletool(h.tb, 'CData',icon, ...
            'TooltipString',labels{i}, 'State','off', ...
            'ClickedCallback',{@toggleButton_callback,i});
    end

    %# create a figure menu (also allows to switch current axis)
    h.cmenu = uimenu('Label','Current Axis');
    for i=1:N
        h.menu(i) = uimenu(h.cmenu, 'Label',labels{i}, ...
            'ForegroundColor',clr(i,:), ...
            'Checked','off', 'Callback',{@toggleButton_callback,i});
    end

    %# start with first axis as current and enable panning tool
    toggleButton_callback([], [], 1)
    pan(h.fig, 'on')

    %# display informational message
    msg = {'Start panning/zooming as usual,', ...
        'and use color buttons to change the active plot.'};
    uiwait(msgbox(msg, 'Help', 'help', 'modal'))

    %% nested callback function
    function toggleButton_callback(o,e,ind)
        %# update toggle buttons
        set(h.toggle, 'State','off')
        set(h.toggle(ind), 'State','on')

        %# update context menu
        set(h.menu, 'Checked','off')
        set(h.menu(ind), 'Checked','on')

        %# make requested axis the current one and bring it forward
        set(h.fig, 'CurrentAxes',h.ax(ind))
        uistack(h.ax(ind), 'top')

        %# make it the only one visible (excluding background axis)
        set(h.ax(1:end-1), 'Visible','off', 'Color','none')
        set(h.ax(ind), 'Visible','on')

        %# make sure legend is always on top
        uistack(h.leg, 'top')

        %# inform which axis is the current one
        title(h.ax(end), labels{ind})
    end
end
```

[image: pic]

As mentioned in the comments, the idea is to create multiple transparent axes one for each line plot. At any moment, only one axis is active, and the limits of that axis are displayed.

You can use any of the interactive tools (zoom, pan, ..) as usual once you have the axis you want selected.

I've included two ways to switch the current active axis: using a custom toolbar with buttons colors matching the respective plot, or using a regular menu added to the figure's menubar.

Other than that, the code is fairly commented and should be easy to follow.